# Jquery append() not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have the following HTML in which I am dynamically creating category buttons by passing category ID and name to a function. The aim is to show product menus on behalf of the category in div `#dvsoft`.

```
<div id="tabbed-nav2">
    <ul id="con1">
        <span>
            <div class="drinks">Drinks</div>
        </span>                                     

        <%for (int i = 0; i < dtCategory.Rows.Count; i++) {
            string str = dtCategory.Rows[i]["CategoryName"].ToString();
            int CategoryId =Convert.ToInt32(dtCategory.Rows[i]["ProductCategoryId"]);
        %>
        <li><a href="javaScript:;" value="<%= CategoryId %>" > <%= str %> </a></li>
        <%} %>
    </ul>
    <div class="center-content">
        <div id="dvSoft"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is the event handler function which calls getDataUsingAjax on click of category button:

```
$('#con1').on('click', 'a', function (e) { //<--CHANGED DATA TO 'a'
    var id = $(this).attr('value');
    //alert("Y123");                
    getDataUsingAjax(id);
});
```

In the following function I am getting a response from handler and appending it to the HTML content of the `#dvSoft` div. The data is returned correctly from every request, but the problem is that only products of the first button (Drinks) are bein displayed. When clicking on any of the other categories none of the products are being shown.

Oddly, if I click five or six times on the second button (Meal) and then click on Drinks again, then the Meal items are shown.

```
function getDataUsingAjax(id) {


            $.get('<%=ResolveUrl("~/AjaxHandler.ashx") %>', { op: 'GetUserData', value: id }, function(data, status) {

                $('#dvSoft').empty();
                var siteContents = data.contents;

                $(data).each(function() {
                    var html = '<div class="items">';
                    html += '<div class="inr-item">';
                    html += '<img src="' + this.Picture + '" style="margin-top: 4px;"/>';
                    html += '</div>';

                    html += '<h4 class="item-title">';
                    html += this.ProductName;
                    html += '</h4>';

                    html += '<span class="item-rate">';
                    html += this.Price;
                    html += '</span>';
                    html += '</div>';


                    $('#dvSoft').append(html);
```

Comment: The `getDataUsingAjax` function is cut off, can you post the remainder of that please? Even if it's just the closing brackets.

Comment: Could you post the generated HTML rather than the server-side code that generates it, please? Would be useful to see the actual structure of the page that we're dealing with. Also, I'm pretty sure putting a `<div>` inside a `<span>` is invalid HTML, so you might want to change that section.

Answer (score 1):

Well you're doing

```
$('#dvSoft').empty();
```

each time you press the link.

On another note, you're iterating "data" instead of "siteContents"

Comment: @Anthony Grist only closing brackets are missing in it.